# LibGDX Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" error

Tags: java, libgdx

So to start off I'm a little new to using libGDX.  I have the book Java Game Development with LibGDX and I'm trying to run the example program in chapter 2.  I am using BlueJ.  Here is the code:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class StarfishCollectorAlpha extends Game
{
private SpriteBatch batch;

private Texture turtleTexture;
private float turtleX;
private float turtleY;
private Rectangle turtleRectangle;

private Texture starfishTexture;
private float starfishX;
private float starfishY;
private Rectangle starfishRectangle;

private Texture oceanTexture;
private Texture winMessageTexture;

private boolean win;

public void create() 
{        
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    
    turtleTexture = new Texture( Gdx.files.internal("assets/turtle-1.png") );
    turtleX = 20;
    turtleY = 20;
    turtleRectangle = new Rectangle( turtleX, turtleY,
        turtleTexture.getWidth(), turtleTexture.getHeight() );
        
    starfishTexture = new Texture( Gdx.files.internal("assets/starfish.png") );
    starfishX = 380;
    starfishY = 380;
    starfishRectangle = new Rectangle( starfishX, starfishY,
        starfishTexture.getWidth(), starfishTexture.getHeight() );
        
    oceanTexture = new Texture( Gdx.files.internal("assets/water.jpg") );
    
    winMessageTexture = new Texture( Gdx.files.internal("assets/you-win.png") );
    
    win = false;
}

public void render() 
{        
     // check user input
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) 
        turtleX--;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
        turtleX++;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) 
        turtleY++;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) 
        turtleY--;
    
    // update turtle rectangle location
    turtleRectangle.setPosition(turtleX, turtleY);
    
    // check win condition: turtle must be overlapping starfish
    if (turtleRectangle.overlaps(starfishRectangle))
        win = true;
   
    // clear screen 
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
    // draw graphics
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw( oceanTexture, 0, 0 );
    if (!win)
        batch.draw( starfishTexture, starfishX, starfishY );
    batch.draw( turtleTexture, turtleX, turtleY );
    if (win)
        batch.draw( winMessageTexture, 180, 180 );
    batch.end();
    
}
```

}

and

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;

public class LauncherAlpha
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Game myGame = new StarfishCollectorAlpha();
    LwjglApplication launcher = new LwjglApplication( myGame, "Starfish Collector", 800, 600 );
}
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
 Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.getCapabilities(GLContext.java:124)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGetError(GL11.java:1299)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Util.checkGLError(Util.java:57)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsContextImplementation.setSwapInterval(WindowsContextImplementation.java:113)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.setSwapInterval(ContextGL.java:232)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setSwapInterval(DrawableGL.java:86)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.setSwapInterval(Display.java:1129)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.setVSyncEnabled(Display.java:1142)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:558)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Has anyone had this error before and does anyone know a workaround?  I understand this has something to do with multi threading, however I have not opened any new threads.  Like I said, I am fairly new to using libGDX so I am not 100% how this works.

Thanks

Comment: Was that the whole error? There should be more error information that will help us, but I suspect there is an issue with threads and how you are starting the game inside the main thread, or the OpenGL context has not been initialized.

Comment: Yes that was the entire error message.  Sorry I didn't include more information, I just didn't know what would be helpful

Comment: What happens if you don't use BlueJ?

Comment: First, try run it in Eclipse or NetBeans IDEs, second - check other examples, common context problem appear when trying access Video memory from another thread, yes, but sometimes its cannot create context, because of problems in drivers

Answer (score 0):

Try to Reset Java Virtual Machine, this can be done by clicking the icon at the bottom right corner of the Bluej main project screen.

I am also following the exact book you are reading and I was able to solve my problem by what I wrote above. Hope that works for you.

[image]